# Stack Exchange Chat Caret Pathfinder

Tags: javascript, stackexchange, chat, userscript

In [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), we have an excessive amount of carets (carrots, if you will) that direct one's attention to another message. For example:

[image: carrots!]

Amidst the confusion, I made a userscript that highlights in yellow the pointed-at message when the message in question is clicked.

```
(function(){
    var elements = {}, messages;

    function findCarrotMessage(){
        messages = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id^='message-']"));
        messages.forEach(function(e){
            if(!elements[e.id] && e.className==="message"){
                elements[e.id] = true;
                e.addEventListener("click", function(s){
                    // count the number of ^'s
                    var num = this.textContent.match(/\^+/g), self = this;
                    if(num){
                        var maxHash = -1;
                        num.forEach(function(k){
                            var destinationMessage = messages[Array.from(messages).indexOf(self)-k.length];
                            destinationMessage.style.background = "yellow";
                            setTimeout(function(e){e.style.background = "";}, 3500, destinationMessage);
                            maxHash = Math.max(destinationMessage.id.slice(destinationMessage.id.indexOf("-")+1), maxHash);
                            elements[self.id] = false;
                        });
                        window.location.hash = "#message-" + maxHash;
                    }
                    this.removeEventListener("click", arguments.callee, false);
                }, false);
            }
        });
    }

    setInterval(findCarrotMessage,50);
})();
```

How can I improve my code? Thanks!

Comment: Please keep white spacing consistent...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### There is still code-golf

Here you have some golfed code:

```
function(e){e.style.background = "";}
```

ungolf it:

```
function(e) {
    e.style.background = ""
}
```

### Run away from `arguments.callee`

> The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) **forbids** use of arguments.callee() in strict mode. Avoid using arguments.callee() by either giving function expressions a name or use a function declaration where a function must call itself.

- [`arguments.callee` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)

---

here you have:

```
e.addEventListener("click", function(s){
```

instead do...

```
var MyFunction = function(s) {
```

and then...

```
e.addEventListener("click", MyFunction);
```

this allows you to then do:

```
this.removeEventListener("click", MyFunction, false);
```

### Don't forget whitespace:

```
e.className==="message"
```

add whitespace around the `===`. There a lot more places where spaces could be added

### Conflicting things

In one part you're using:

```
 Array.prototype.slice.call
```

in another you are using:

```
Array.from
```

you should probably decide on one

### Don't to a ton of things in one line

```
maxHash = Math.max(destinationMessage.id.slice(destinationMessage.id.indexOf("-")+1), maxHash)
```

that is *waaaay* to much in one line for a code reviewer like me ;) to be supporting. This:

```
destinationMessage.id.slice(destinationMessage.id.indexOf("-")+1)
```

looks like it can become a regex:

```
( /-(\d+)/.exec(destinationMessage.id) || [])[1]
```

or even better:

```
destinationMessage.id.split("-")[1]
```

### use `.getAttribute`

rather than something like:

```
e.id
```

prefer:

```
e.getAttribute("id")
```

### Remove all code-golf

```
var destinationMessage = messages[Array.from(messages).indexOf(self)-k.length]
```

you should split this into multiple variables. What if `indexOf` returns -1, you should handle that because otherwise your code will error and completely breakdown

### use `.bind` rather than `self = this`

You're having to introduce `self` because the forEach's function creates a new scope. Instead use `.bind` and keep your old scope

```
num.forEach(function(k) {
    // code
}.bind(this))
```

Even better, use `e.target` to get the element that's been clicked. I highly recommending avoiding using `this` in lambdas to store data.

Comment: Right on the first point, the "ungolfed" version is missing the `;`. Instead of your `( /-(\d+)/.exec(destinationMessage.id) || [])[1]`, one can use `destinationMessage.id.replace(/^.*-(\d+).*$/, '$1')`, which is more bullet-proof than your short `.split('-')`. Also, there's nothing wrong with `e.id`. Why waste time using the DOM when the DOM already wasted time for that `e.id`? Every single instance of `Element` has that attribute. It's a global attribute on DOM.

Comment: not using `getAttribute` is fine in this case but it often dissolves into bad practice with people using `foo[computed_property]` which is insecure and bad easily break.

Comment: That's quite a late answer. Yes, I see where you are coming from, but, your practice also leads to things like `e.getAttribute("onclick")` and other weird stuffs.

Answer (score 7):

## One line variable declaration

Please avoid declaring variables on the same line:

> ```
> var elements = {}, messages;
> ```

It's also a great way to royally mess up scope issues if you do it on *two* lines but still with spaces.

> ```
> var notAGlobal //, a comma might be here
>     aGlobal;
> ```

---

## Globals

`messages` doesn't need to be a global, you reassign it every time you call the function.

---

## `apply` vs `call`

I always found that `apply` was more useful than `call`, in that you can specify parameters as an array (vs manually listing them). There's not much of a difference, but it's still good to know your options.

[See this SO answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986909/3296811)

---

## Indentation level

Anything that looks like this can be cleaned up:

> ```
> function(){
>    if(!whatever){
>        //...
>    }
> }
> ```

You can reverse the condition and `continue` or `return` to reduce the level of indentation in some of your code:

> ```
> if(!elements[e.id] && e.className==="message"){
> ```

---

## Missing whitespace

You're missing whitespace in a few lines, like this one:

> ```
> if(!elements[e.id] && e.className==="message"){
> ```

You should always have whitespace on both sides of a binary operator.

> ```
> setTimeout(function(e){e.style.background = "";}
> ```

---

## `setTimeout`

Instead of using `setTimeout`, you can bind the function to an `eventListener`.

Specifically, if you use the `DOMNodeInserted` event, you can call the message check every time a node is added (this will trigger on stars, but hey, if nothing happens, then nothing happens)

If you did, however, want to take the event triggering to a lower amount, you could consider using `MutationObservers`, but I always found them painful.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', findCarrotMessage);
```

---

## `findCarrotMessage`

This name is confusing and incorrect.

It doesn't find carrot messages, it iterates through the messages and replaces text.

You should consider breaking this function up into smaller functions and using a name that suits (and accurately describes the action) beyond a vague description.

---

## `Array.from(messages).indexOf(self)-k.length`

Uh, the second parameter in `Array.prototype.forEach` is the index of the item. Use that instead of recasting the array.

However, if you had a genuine reason to recast the array, you shouldn't do it that way. The third parameter of `Array.prototype.forEach` is the array itself. (wow, it's almost like they thought about these things :p)

---

## `maxHash`:

This would be better termed `lastHash` than `maxHash`.

You shouldn't have single lines this complex:

> ```
> Math.max(destinationMessage.id.slice(destinationMessage.id.indexOf("-")+1), maxHash);
> ```

You should break this up into components before something gets that complex in a single line.